# How to modify the date?

Tags: date, blackberry, simpledateformat

I cannot get the `add` function in Blackberry Java.

```
// Date
private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
private static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
public static final String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())
        .toString();
```

The `cal` variable don't have `add` function because I want to reduce 1 day from current date.

The [source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-date-time-date-manipulation-java/) stated that used `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTime() - DateTimeUtilities.ONEDAY);
```

Updated, based on [ecb0628](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814576/ecb0628)'s answer and [paulkayuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980432/paulkayuk)'s comment.

Check [Calendar](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html), [getTimeInMilis()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29), [setTimeInMillis(long millis)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29), and [DateTimeUtilities.ONEDAY](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/DateTimeUtilities.html#ONEDAY).

Comment: Note that there is no need to define your own tick constant for one day etc. when programming in Java for BlackBerry.  The BlackBerry API has these defined for you already see e.g. DateTimeUtilities.ONEDAY = Number of ticks in one day

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works when using Java SE. I haven't verified using BlackBerry Java ME yet. But, given that I am only using functions that exist in both the [SE version of Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and the [BlackBerry version of Calendar](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/index.html), hence I have a good feeling about the accuracy of this solution. Append these lines to your code:

```
long curTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
curTime -= 1000*60*60*24;
cal.setTimeInMillis(curTime);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString());
```

Comment: I missed `getTimeInMillis()` in `Calendar`. Nice answer.

Comment: see also BlackBerry DateTimeUtilities.ONEDAY for you milliseconds (ticks) in one day